# Adding second virtual host with different Ruby and Passanger version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, deployment, passenger

I have main Rails app working on system Ruby and Passanger. Following virtual host works just fine:

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
  ServerName domain.com

  DocumentRoot /home/john/apps/main_app/public

  PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.29
    PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby

  <Directory /home/deploy/apps/main_app/public>
    PassengerEnabled On
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I want to add second virtual host for my second app working on different Ruby/Passanger versions and different domain but on same machine:

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
  ServerName domain2.com
  DocumentRoot /home/deploy/apps/app/public
  PassengerRoot /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@app/gems/passenger-4.0.59
  PassengerRuby /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby

  <Directory /home/deploy/apps/app/public>
    PassengerEnabled On
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After enabling second VirtualHost the first one (main app) is not working anymore. In browser I have 403 error. Same situation for second app.

Error log from main application:

```
[Sun Feb 15 13:29:08.596451 2015] [autoindex:error] [pid 53380] [client x.x.x.x] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/john/apps/main_app/public: 
No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) 
found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: x
```

After disabling second app first one is working. How can I make to work both apps in the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configurations are incorrect. The two virtual hosts are using two different Passenger versions, and loading two different Ruby versions.

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
  PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.29
  PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
</VirtualHost>
```

vs

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
  PassengerRoot /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@app/gems/passenger-4.0.59
  PassengerRuby /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I've changed second vhost PassangerRoot to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.29 and its working! Thanks Simone